# How to select XML attributes like what we do in SQL command in Python?

Tags: python, sql, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have an XML file which contains lots or rows :

```
<rows>
<row>
<cell>1</cell>
<cell>09:49:25</cell>
<cell>100000</cell>
<cell>17060.00</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell>2</cell>
<cell>09:49:25</cell>
<cell>100000</cell>
<cell>17060.00</cell>
</row>
.
.
.
<row>
<cell>28051</cell>
<cell>12:30:00</cell>
<cell>2063</cell>
<cell>16700.00</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell>28052</cell>
<cell>12:30:00</cell>
<cell>100</cell>
<cell>16700.00</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell>28053</cell>
<cell>12:30:00</cell>
<cell>716</cell>
<cell>16700.00</cell>
</row>
</rows>
```

The first cell shows the time and the second and third cells show the number and value columns. I need to select all numbers which have less than 20 and the time is the same. In SQL command we can do this like this:

```
SELECT SUM(number) FROM mytable where value < 20 GORUP BY time;
```

I have more queries in this XML file,

Is there any way to do it without saving my XML in SQL server? is it efficient if there is a way to do it? Or the best way is to store in my DB and select queries from SQL server and drop the table?

Comment: Have you used BeautifulSoup with lxml?

Comment: @BlakeG Is it possible to select and group by in BeautifulSoup? do you have any examples? I couldn't find it. I want to know the most efficient way

Comment: First, your SQL is not valid. Did you want to run an aggregate on `number`? And it is not clear why MySQL is tagged. Also, your elements are not clearly named. But generally, `XPath` can parse XML data by conditional logic and node path expressions. For more sophisticated calculations like grouping, use `XPath`'s sibling, `XSLT` (which like SQL is a declarative language with select and grouping functions).

Comment: Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) these concepts in Python and give it a try and come back with a *specific* issue related to your implementation.